# Change Bootstrap breadcrumbs divider color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and am overriding `.btn-primary` with the following css to change the color a bit

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090;
    border-color: #204d74
}
```

I'm trying to use [this breadcrumb example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/triangle-breadcrumbs-arrows) but when I do, the arrow points (triangle bits) that separate the items are not the same color as the buttons.  This happens on the normal state as well as the hover/active state.

What CSS properties do I need to edit to make these triangles the same color as my buttons?

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid rgb(173, 173, 173);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
/** The Spacing **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 24px;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
  padding: 6px 18px 6px 24px;
}
/** Primary button **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #428bca;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #357ebd;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 10px solid #3276b1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 10px solid #285e8e;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Breadcrumb Primary</h2>
    <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Snippets</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Breadcrumbs</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the CSS you need to use on normal state:

```
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 10px solid #327CBA;
}
```

This is the CSS you need to use on hover state:

```
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-primary:hover:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 10px solid #286090;
}
```

Just find the definitions in your CSS file and replace it with the code above.
You just need to change the colors for the normal state and hover state actually.

Comment: works fine. But also make sure it works when crumbs are hovered

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Yup, it works but doesnt fix the issue when hovered. wazaaaap, how do I fix it on hover?

Comment: Got it, thanks, I totally didnt realize that the `border` property governed the arrows. I was going nuts trying to change the background color of everything I could think of.

Comment: You should use firebug or some other tool for inspecting elements (right click on the page > inspect element). It will help you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the arrows altogether

```
.btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child)::before,
.btn.btn-primary:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: none;
}
```